# How do I get rid of a local heroku remote or app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku tells me it recognises multiple apps. But when I want to remove one it says the app is not there. How can I get rid of it?

```
➜  sample_app git:(user-microposts) heroku pg:reset DATABASE
 ›   Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
 ›      Usage: --remote rails-tutorial-josufst
 ›         or: --app pure-crag-52432
 ›      Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
 ›      Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
 ›      Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
 ›      Heroku remotes in repo:
 ›      rails-tutorial-josufst (heroku)
 ›   pure-crag-52432 (rails-tutorial-josufst)
 ›
 ›      https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments
➜  sample_app git:(user-microposts) heroku apps:destroy pure-crag-52432
 ▸    Couldn't find that app.
```

On the Heroku platform there is only one repository.

[Only one repository on Heroky](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvqYx.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is referring to the remote reference on your local git repository.

Try this to see what's set as remote locally:

```
git remote -v
```

Then do this to remove one of them

```
git remote remove <name>
```

Comment: How is heroku involved in this? It has nothing to do with heroku?

Comment: To deploy your app to Heroku, you add a remote origin that corresponds to Heroku. That's how you can push to the Heroku git to deploy your app. So if you've had multiple apps in the past, it's likely that you have multiple remote repositories.